# SSRS - Add a value from previous rows based on value which start with ~

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am working on a complicated scenario where I need to show a dollar amount of previous lines until a tilde is present. Here is an example :

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ownf5.jpg)

As per the above example, if the line starts with ~ [tilde], it should show its own retail amount in 'Retail on quote' field. If the line does not start with ~ then the 'Retail on quote' should be blank but subtotal in the background to show it on line with ~ adding tilde line amount as well. Any input will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the following Stored Procedure in DB and call this procedure in SSRS:
(Note: I have used MS SQL Server as a DB and created the similar table in DB as you shown in the example image except column "Retail_On_QUOTE")

```
create or alter procedure test_sproc 
as
begin
create table #tbl1 (col1 char(10), Retail int, Retail_On_QUOTE int)
insert into #tbl1 select Col1, retail, 0 from tbl1
declare c1 cursor for select Col1, retail from #tbl1
declare @total int=0, @col1 char(10), @retail int, @total2 int=0
open c1
fetch next from c1 into @col1, @retail
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
begin
    if  left(@col1,1) = '~' 
        begin

            set @total = @retail+@total2
            set @total2 = 0
        end
    else
        begin
            set @total2 = @total2+@retail
            set @total = 0
        end
    print @total
    update #tbl1 set Retail_On_QUOTE = @total where col1 = @col1
    fetch next from c1 into @col1, @retail
end
close c1
deallocate c1
select col1, Retail, Retail_On_QUOTE from #tbl1
end
```

Comment: I can use the same idea in the VB code to pull this off. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a VB function (Code Section of the Report) and call the function with line name and $ Amount.
Add to a sum and return the value to display it. In a second Function you could return the sum and set it to 0.

Not sure this is all correct VB, but it would look something like this:

```
Public Function SumUp(line As String, value As Double) As Double
        sum = sum + value
        Return value
End Function

Public Function GetSum() As Double
        Dim v = sum
        sum = 0
        Return sum
End Function
```

In your Value-Field call the function like this:

```
=Code!SumUp(Fields!Line, Fields!Value)
```

In your Sum-Field call the GetSum function in a IIF expression like

```
=IIF(pseudo:Fields starts with~, "", Code!GetSum())
```